# Taping the lock screen player controller opens the wrong web app

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I have a problem with a flutter web app. I'm using the just audio plugin and audio service plugin. When playing an audio file while beeing on the lock screen, taping the lock screen player controller opens the wrong web app, which has no audio player at all. Any idea why and how to set that properly?